# Number of Unique Positive Integer Solutions

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I have the equation $x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_r = n$, for each $x_i \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ ($\mathbb{N}$ does *not* contain $0$).

We know that the number of solutions to this equation is ${n-1\choose r-1}$. But what if we wanted to find the number of UNIQUE solutions to the given equation? ${n-1\choose r-1}$ overcounts the solutions $(y_1, y_2, ..., y_r)$ with all of it's permutations $(y_1',  y_2', ..., y_r')$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Comment: To follow up vadim123's comment, it sounds like you are specifically referring to *restricted* partitions (*into $r$ non-empty parts*).

Comment: Probably you had in mind $y_r$, not $y_n$ (it would be even better to use $x$ instead of $y$). There is no closed form for the partition function, but the recurrence relation $p_r(n) = p_r(n − r) + p_{r−1}(n − 1)$ may be of use.

Comment: I knew that if I found the number of distinct solutions to this equation, I would be able to find a closed form for the partition function, and that's why I thought finding a formula for the partition function would be easy.
Guess it wasn't!